# Test a private void method which creates an object of different class

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I am trying to test one of the private void methods which creates an object of different class.

Currently the snippet of code throws null pointer exception. Is the error caused because the object of SendMail class is not mocked?

Method to be tested -

```
private void sendActivationCode(MailInfoDTO mailInfoBn) throws SystemException {
        **SendMail sm = new SendMail();**
        try {
            sm.setTo(mailInfoBn.getMailTo());
            sm.setFrom(mailInfoBn.getMailFrom());
            sm.setMailHost(PropertiesHelper.getProperty("smtp_server"));
            sm.setPopServerHost(PropertiesHelper.getProperty("smtp_server"));
            sm.setRequireAuth(true);
            sm.setPopUserName(PropertiesHelper.getProperty("smtp_auth_user"));
            sm.setPopPassword(PropertiesHelper.getProperty("smtp_auth_pass"));
            sm.setMessageBody(mailInfoBn.getMessageBody());
            sm.setSubject(mailInfoBn.getMessageSubject());
            sm.setDebug(false);
            sm.setKeepCopyInOS(false);
            sm.sendSMTP();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new SystemException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Test class snippet -

```
ProfileNotificationBO profileNotificationBOSpy = PowerMockito.spy(profileNotificationBO);
            PowerMockito.doNothing().when(profileNotificationBOSpy, "sendActivationCode", Mockito.any(MailInfoDTO.class));
```

Stacktrace -

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Failed with following error: com.common.exceptions.SystemException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.profile.api.bo.ProfileNotificationBO.sendActivationCode(ProfileNotificationBO.java:791)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1873)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:773)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:638)
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:93)
at com.profile.api.bo.TestProfileNotificationBO.testGenerateActivationCodeWhenMblNotRegistered(TestProfileNotificationBO.java:1148)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.profile.api.bo.ProfileNotificationBO.sendActivationCode(ProfileNotificationBO.java:778)

at com.profile.api.bo.TestProfileNotificationBO.testGenerateActivationCodeWhenMblNotRegistered(TestProfileNotificationBO.java:1166)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
```

Comment: Please add stacktrace to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by removing the unnecessary snippet.

```
ProfileNotificationBO profileNotificationBOSpy = PowerMockito.spy(profileNotificationBO);
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(profileNotificationBOSpy, "sendActivationCode", Mockito.any(MailInfoDTO.class));
```

The SendMail class needs to be mocked to pass the test case.